# How do I learn about markup?

Tags: support, faq-proposed

So everyone knows that math.stackexchange supports Tex tags, but what other tags are supported? Is there any info out there the markup supported on stackexchange sites?

In particular, I was looking for a way to put part of my question "under cut", ie, hide it and put a link that expands contents on click.

Comment: The "under cut" term is unfamiliar to me, but it sounds like you are talking about [spoiler tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/503/). If so, this is an [open feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text/60012#60012).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[A brief guide to markdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) can be found by clicking the question mark above the text box for writing questions or answers:
[image]

In addition to markdown, [many html tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) are supported.

Comment: You know, that page doesn't mention the [La]TeX (like) syntax support. That would probably be a good thing to add...

Answer (score 5):

The markup that SE sites use is called markdown.  You can read about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3):

This information would be really useful in the faq.